# Does rem units on the HTML element make any sense?

Tags: css, units-of-measurement

The CSS unit rem is short for “root em”. When used in CSS `2rem` evaluates to “two times the font size on the root element” which in an HTML document is two times the font size on the HTML element. I know that I can change the font size on the HTML element by specifying it in e.g. `html { font-size: 10px; }`. But does it make any sense to do so using rem units? What does it even mean? Does the spec say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If font-size is not specified, browser will use the default size (which is in most cases 16px, but I can't find it being specified anywhere in the CSS specification).

Now what using rem in root element will do is using that default value and multiplying it, 1rem = 16px, 2rem = 32px.

The spec seems to confirm that: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#rem

> **rem unit**
>
> Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element. **When specified on the font-size property of the root element, the rem units refer to the property’s initial value.**

I wouldn't say it makes any sense, since relying on browser's default values in CSS isn't necessarily a good idea, but if you want to multiply the browser's default font size you can.