# Are rems and ems equivalent when used at root level?

Tags: html, css, font-scaling

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59864522/5825294) I see what's the definition of `rem` in the spec:

> rem unit
>
> Equal to the computed value of `font-size` on the root element. When specified in the `font-size` property of the root element, or in a document with no root element, `1rem` is equal to the initial value of the `font-size` property.

And the definition of `em` is:

> em unit
>
> Equal to the computed value of the `font-size` property of the element on which it is used.

To me this implies that `1em == 1rem` by definition when used at `:root`.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```css
:root {
  font-size:40px;
  border-top:   1rem solid red;
  border-bottom:1em  solid green;
}
```